# Insert multiple data in the same page using `Insert Merge Field` from Excel to Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have a `Excel` like this and I want to import the dynamic data into `Word` using `Merge Field`
[click this to see the excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LcSP.png).

I have a A4 size with Landscape oriented Word. Then I need to separate the A4 into 4 columns like this.
[click this to see the word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzCYK.png)
From the Excel I provided above, I need to call the `<<Customer's Purchase Order Date>>` and  `<<MHW SO Ref>>` using `Insert Merge Field`.

Situation:
I need to call the dynamic data in ascending index into Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4

**Expected Result:**

index[20] refer line 21 in excel... Column 1 = ['6308', 'SO00017826']

index[21] refer line 22 in excel... Column 2 = ['6315', 'SO00017904']

index[22] refer line 23 in excel... Column 3 = ['6317', 'SO00018018']

index[23] refer line 24 in excel... Column 4 = ['BMPO,BEDPO', 'SO00018124']

but ended up repeating the same result

**Actual Result:**

index[20] refer line 21 in excel... Column 1 = ['6308', 'SO00017826']

index[20] refer line 22 in excel... Column 2 = ['6308', 'SO00017826']

index[20] refer line 23 in excel... Column 3 = ['6308', 'SO00017826']

index[20] refer line 24 in excel... Column 4 = ['6308', 'SO00017826']

is that possible to reach the expected result by using Word?
Any idea?

Comment: I do not think so. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3. The idea is that you have multiple records (rows) with the same sort of information in the Excel columns. Mailmerge formats the information for each record called by mergefields that use the column headers. You can have multiple records on a page, certainly, but you must be getting the same information from each record.

Comment: done, i find another way to do it, thanks! 
[Start Mail Merge] > [Directory], then [Finish & Merge]